# Is it possible to create an SQL constraint on a group of rows (Azure SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, constraints, unique-constraint

Is it possible to create an SQL constraint or index of some sort on a group of rows? Like a unique constraint but applied to multiple rows. Rows could be duplicated but it would not be possible to have more than one variation of each group. Simplified example:

Given the following table with inserted data:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ValueColumn INT NOT NULL,
    DateColumn DATETIME NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1, '2001-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1, '2001-01-01 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2, '2002-02-02 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2, '2002-02-02 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2, '2002-02-02 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3, '2003-03-03 00:00:00.000')
```

Inserting this row should be possible:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3, '2003-03-03 00:00:00.000')
```

But trying to insert this row should result in an error:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3, '2004-04-04 00:00:00.000') --> Violates constraint
```

Essentially the following queries should always return no rows:

```
SELECT [ValueColumn], [DateColumn]
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [ValueColumn], [DateColumn]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [DateColumn]) > 1

SELECT [ValueColumn], [DateColumn]
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY [ValueColumn], [DateColumn]
HAVING MAX(DateColumn) != MIN(DateColumn)
```

I understand this could be done with a trigger or manual clean up process but I was wondering if there was a way to add it as a constraint on the data model itself.

Comment: By the look of things DateColumn is functionally dependent on ValueColumn so this should be in a different table with just the distinct values of `ValueColumn, DateColumn` and a unique constraint on `ValueColumn `

Comment: `create view dbo.myview with schemabinding
as
select ValueColumn, DateColumn, count_big(*) as cnt
from dbo.MyTable
group by ValueColumn, DateColumn;

create unique clustered index uclxmyview on dbo.myview(ValueColumn);`